# How to refresh the data on other user's interface when some user edits the data

Tags: sql, wpf, vb.net, winforms, sql-server-2008-r2

In a VB.net application I have a SQL interface, I have a `users` table in the SQL database for users of this application, all of them see the same data now when a user clicks a button changes are saved in the sql and data is refreshed for that user, however I want the data to be refreshed for all users as soon as some user clicks that button.

Ideas I have

1. refreshing data every second, which is not good
2. SQL trigger to vb.net which I need more clarification about!

What would be the most effective way?

i would like a work around without timers!

Thanks

Comment: Is this a web application or a desktop app?

Comment: desktop app, i am using wpf and normal grid control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### SQL Server Notification Services

SQL provides subscription for notifications that provide mechanisms related to your requirements.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172483(v=sql.90).aspx

> ***Note**: removed since you later provided info you're using SQL Server 2008 R2*

### Old trick with `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher`

The other way is to create a SQL trigger on your table that does a simple file timestamp change. File itself is 0 bytes in size so we're not writing anything to it, making it a fast operation.

All clients then watch this file for modifications and when it happens watcher triggers a change event in which your clients would simply reload their data.

```
CREATE TRIGGER DataChanged
ON YourTable
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
    EXEC master..xsp_UpdateSignalFile 'YourTable.DataChanged'
```

The idea of this CLR stored procedure is to be as fast as possible to keep it scalable. IN case of heavy load data server this could likely be even optimised by using external processes to update file...

You can find the code for the CLR stored procedure in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188758.aspx) that is actually related to web forms, but you don't need other things than this CLR procedure. And maybe the explanation of how the whole system works.

Your clients would then be using `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher` to watch for file changes on some network location (where the procedure would be updating files) and update their data when change happens.

**Simple and elegant trick** that doesn't use polling or unnecessary requests to the data server. You can of course have triggers on several tables each changing a different file and depending on the form you're displaying on the client you'd then watch that particular file for the lifetime of the form. When user changes context to a different data your client app releases file watcher (and creates a new one of needed for a different file).

Comment: SQL Server Notification Services are not supported any longer by SQL Server 2008, i wouldn't have asked ;)

Comment: @user1590636: you haven't provided SQL version when I started writing my answer. The second solution on the other hand is elegant and should work well in your scenario.

Comment: @ RobertKoritnik what about recording the ip of each user that logs in to the application, and when the user click the save changes button a message is send to all those computers running the application over TCP/IP, then i check the message and call the refresh function, is that good?

Comment: @user1590636: I think you'd be chasing your own tail with that solution because if you'd be storing your users somewhere (i.e. DB), you'd then have to read that data every time you'd make a DB change to notify currently logged in users. Or have a polling again to update user list in memory. I don't think that would be a good solution because instead of watching for one change you'd have to watch a different one and notify clients. It also means you'd have to develop a more complex update system yourself compared to this simple CLR SP and using out of the box system classes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is a Windows Form App, rather than an aspx web application? I would suggest reloading the form on some sort of user raised event.

Answer (score 0):

Simple,

You can't do that. Your browser only pulls data once and except for a few things like coockies your browser will not remember anything.

You only option is to refresh the page every 5 or 10 secons or so. This can only be done using javascript. Fortunatly Visual studio privides you with some sort of javascript. This will prevent the browser from refresshing. So you whon't hear that klik every 5 sec.

Add an updatepanel around the controls you want to refresh.
Then add a postbacktrigger and set it to 5000 miliseconds.

Add to "page load" --> resresh your control.

A better way would be to add a webmethod that will only send you the data but above works fine and is easy to implement.

Good luck.

Comment: Well, you don't have to reload all data. Only the data that changed... This could be done using a table in which you store updates (filled by sql triggers).

Comment: @Kek i am already loading only the changed data, but i am looking for a solution without a timer!

Comment: @Danny its not a web application :)

Comment: Even if this was a web application this isn't a valid answer... Polling isn't the only possible solution these days... Check Reactive extensions.