# c++ file datestamp change by ms sql xp called by trigger to allow refresh vb.net forms application

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm using SQL2012 and VS2012.

I'd like to implement this solution for watching a file's date and time stamp which is updated by a dll when a trigger on a SQL table is fired.

[Here is what I'm trying to do.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584220/how-to-refresh-the-data-on-other-users-interface-when-some-user-edits-the-data)

Which references a [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188758.aspx)

I’ve followed the instructions but got this:

```
Msg 17750, Level 16, State 0, Procedure xsp_UpdateSignalFile, Line 1
Could not load the DLL XSP.dll, or one of the DLLs it references. Reason: 193(%1 is not a valid Win32 application.).
```

I’m assuming because I’m using SQL2012 64-bit.

I downloaded the XSP.DLL source and looking at in the VS2012 but can’t get it to compile, even after finding myself a copy of [opends60.lib](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b814f665-b058-492e-9612-94dd19626e21/sql-server-native-client-sdk-doesnt-include-x64-libs?forum=sqldataaccess)

```
Error 4    error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _srv_rpcparams referenced in function _xsp_UpdateSignalFile     C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\xsp.dll\WickedCode0304\XSP\XSP.obj  XSP
```

Can a C++ wizard help me compile this to 64bit or am I going wrong earlier?

It is saying it can't resolve some received params?

The .cpp file looks like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <srv.h>

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Entry point

extern "C" BOOL WINAPI DllMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD dwReason,
    LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    return TRUE;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Exported functions

extern "C" __declspec (dllexport)
ULONG __GetXpVersion ()
{
   return ODS_VERSION;
}

extern "C" __declspec (dllexport)
SRVRETCODE xsp_UpdateSignalFile (SRV_PROC *srvproc)
{
    //
    // Make sure an input parameter is present.
    //
    if (srv_rpcparams (srvproc) == 0)
        return -1;

    //
    // Extract the file name from the input parameter.
    //
    BYTE bType;
    char file[256];
    ULONG ulMaxLen = sizeof (file);
    ULONG ulActualLen;
    BOOL fNull;

    if (srv_paraminfo (srvproc, 1, &bType, &ulMaxLen, &ulActualLen,
        (BYTE*) file, &fNull) == FAIL)
        return -1;

    if (bType != SRVBIGCHAR && bType != SRVBIGVARCHAR)
        return -1;

    file[ulActualLen] = 0;

    //
    // Update the file's time stamp.
    //
    char path[288] = "C:\\AspNetSql\\";
    lstrcat (path, file);

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile (path, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        CloseHandle (hFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working with using SQL Server 2008 SP3 Dev 64-bit and VS 2012 Ultimate running on Win 7 Pro 64-bit. Here's what I did:

1. Created a new `Empty Project` from the `VC++`templates in VS and added an empty C++ file.
2. Changed platform to `x64` in the `Configuration manager`.
3. Changed the `Configuration Type` to `Dynamic library (.dll)` under `Configuration Properties/General`.
4. Installed the [SQL x64 native client](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/4/D/44DBDE61-B385-4FC2-A67D-48053B8F9FAD/sqlncli_x64.msi) including the `SQL Server Native Client SDK` to get the `opends60.lib`. I'm not sure the SDK component is actually needed.
5. Added `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\SDK\Lib\x64` to `Additional library directories` in the Linker options. This was were the native client was installed.
6. Added `opends60.lib` to `Additional` `dependencies` in the Linker options.
7. Compiled without errors.
8. Created the output directory that the `XSP.dll` uses: `C:\AspNetSql\`.
9. Copied the `XSP.dll` to the directory created in step 8.
10. Installed the extended stored procedure using:

    `USE master`
    `EXEC sp_addextendedproc 'xsp_UpdateSignalFile', 'C:\AspNetSql\XSP.dll'`
    `GRANT EXECUTE ON xsp_UpdateSignalFile TO PUBLIC`
11. Executed it using `master..xsp_UpdateSignalFile 'Quotes.Quotations'`and verified it worked by confirming that the file `Quotes.Quotations` was created in the output directory.

If you have any questions or want clarification on any step I can add screenshots or provide more information.

Comment: Fantastic.  So many little config changes a non-cpp guy would never figure out.  Thanks!

Couple of additional notes for future visitors here.  1) I got a "unable to start program" error on compilation in VS,  but the .dll is created anyway....  I don't want to "start it!!!"  and 2) the .dll could not be found in the \aspNetSQL folder.  I had to put it in my windows\system32 directory.   

Thanks again!

Comment: @bendecko Did you perhaps compile the project using `Debug/Start Without Debugging`? If you just build the project using `Build/Build Solution` (`Ctrl+Shift+B`) you shouldn't get the `Unable to start program`error.

Comment: Yes that is it.  I will get there in the end. Maybe.  Thanks for the help!